# SQLite Syntax (order by causing error)

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite

Looking for some syntax help for SQLite, a very odd thing is happening.  I am running the query on an iPhone.

Here is the query that fails: (Assume that the tables are correct, this runs great in the firefox sqlite plugin)

```
  select tcodes.DisplayOrder, StatusText, StatusCode  
    from tcodes 
    join tcode_transitions on tcode_transitions.available = tcodes.UNID 
   where StatusCode = 'AAA' 
order by tcodes.DisplayOrder
```

To get it to run, I have to remove the order by clause, which seems a bit strange.

Here is the call:

```
// Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access

        int rtn = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, nil);
        if(rtn != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"SQL Error: %d",rtn);
            sqlite3_close(database);
        }
    }
```

in the above, rtn is == 1, which indicates a SQL error.

Again, the query runs great outside the phone.  Is it possible that the SQL libraries on the iPhone have a different syntax for the order by?

Comment: Please tell us _how_ the query fails?
And try adding DisplayOrder to select clause...

Comment: Can we get a snippet of the error message?

Comment: Some databases require the column(s) specified in the ORDER BY to also exist in the SELECT clause...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: You might want to post that as an answer.

Comment: Great comments, I updated the example and tried including the order by field in the select, no joy.

Comment: Is it possible the query is getting truncated before being sent?

Comment: What does `sqlite3_errmsg` return?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, OMG Ponies was the solution.  I had tried, but forgot to delete the application on the simulator to force the database to re-copy to the phone.  The last comment from tom pointed me to why I was not seeing the issue.  Make it an answer so I assign it so others can find it.  And thanks everyone, will sleep way better tonight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [`sqlite3_errmsg`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) (or `sqlite3_errmsg16`) to get more information about error.
2. Try adding DisplayOrder to select clause. 
   Some databases require that all columns in ORDER BY clause are also present in SELECT clause.